# Shortcut to hide a Tool Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

We can **close** a Tool Window with `Shift+Esc`. What is the shortcut to **hide** a Tool Window? I have tried `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+H` to no avail.

For example, when the Locals window is open, I can close it with `Shift+Esc` but not hide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing a tool window preserves its state and actually works like hiding. Maybe you want to assign a shortcut to the **Window.AutoHide** command (also available in the main Window menu).

Comment: In my case, I have to use `Window.Hide`