# What is the shortcut to auto hide a Tool Window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Every Visual Studio tool window contains a litte pin button to toggle the window between "pin" and "auto hide".

I would like to know if there is a shortcut for this command because I very often need to access it.

I already know that there is a command to close the tool window (Window.CloseToolWindow, Shift + Esc), but I prefer it to stay open.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372383/shortcut-to-hide-a-tool-window

Comment: Thank you. But my question aimes at knowing whether there is a single command to toggle the window state between closed and pinned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure there is a shortcut to controll the autohide/show of the toolbox. I think you need to manage it without it with like "CTRL+ALT+X" and Ctrl+SHIFT